# Cannot login with auth.basic in L4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I installed 2 versions of Laravel. The one installed in localhost (Windows - Wampserver) is to test function auth.basic & login normally. But the other installed in server Centos is unable to login, I tried again & again but haven't found the causes yet :(
Anybody know how to check & solve this situation? Tks.

Comment: Please add details about your configuration and what you have tried. we cannot help you with so few information.

Comment: I dont know to show you which part of config, because generally L4 that has just been install have no installed config. This is the code Route that I created account & test auth. http://paste.laravel.com/qBC I use PHP 5.4.13. Support Mcrypt

Answer (score 2):

In your code in http://paste.laravel.com/qBt , you are using 2 routes with same destination `/`. Should be one:

```php
Route::get('/', array('before'=>'auth.basic', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}));
```

For test user creation use another route, `/user` or so and hit it once using your browser.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the problem you said. But that code is just a demo, in fact I will comment code each part to perform individually.

Comment: Is your L4 version up to date? `auth.basic` is a new feature. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/develop

Comment: I use the latest version of L4 (have just downloaded & installed today)

Comment: I met this error again when instaling Laravel in Mac OS X :( I use MAMP PRO & PHP 5.4.4